# Can I connect to a Bluetooth device by scanning a QR code?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I would have to build two apps (Android and iOS) and control some equipment via Bluetooth. For clarification, i cannot just use OS device discovery to connect to the equipment because there's hundreds of them and their position is very important (as well as the user's position when issuing commands), thus it's less of a hassle for operators to just point the phone's camera at a QR code and connect than having to go through a long list of devices with mangled names.

I haven't found many details about specifically using a QR code for bluetooth connections, but i figured that people experienced with this kind of communication will be able to say if it can be done. Please correct me if i'm wrong, but my understanding is that a bluetooth socket is not that different from a TCP one and a connection could be established by knowing the server's credentials.

- Can I use a QR code to store device credentials that I can use to establish a connection? It doesn't really matter how much information needs storing, the QR code can contain any sensitive information.
- Is there anything more, apart from the UUID, that would need storing on the QR code?
- Is it simpler to configure the device as a server and the phone as a client for this specific request? There will be multiple operators that will need to work with these devices.
- This is specific to Android and iOS, but if the points above were possible, would I get an OS pop-up window for each connection? Would skipping the discovery step save the operator the hassle of having to confirm the connection to the OS?
- If the target device is configured as a server, each with its UUID as the QR code, can i scan that code and open a socket to that very device without manually connecting to it from the phone's menu?

Comment: Are you using Bluetooth Classic or Bluetooth Low Energy?

Comment: Bluetooth programming is always annoying on mobile devices. You could use Java Sockets over an internet connection, and the QR Code would contain the IP Address and Port information.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan there was no request for what type of BL to use. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @AuraLee I didn't mention it as i didn't think it was necessary but i will use python/c++ for Android. I saw that there are frameworks that implement java libraries for this kind of task. I cannot use eth sockets because the devices don't have this functionality and they are not connected to any network.

Comment: The type of Bluetooth does matter; iOS apps can only communicate with Bluetooth Low Energy devices. A QR code can't identify a device directly. Your app would need to connect to each device, query a characteristic to see if it was the device it was interested in (the code from the QR). Over time your app could build a table of QR codes to device identifiers. (Each iOS device sees a different identifier for a given device)

Comment: @conopizda2 Paulw11 explained it perfectly :)

Comment: @Paulw11 but would that mean that i would still have to go through that long list of devices, connect to it **and then** use my app to check if it was the correct one? That would make it an even bigger hassle. I am looking for a way to skip having to scroll through a very long list of devices and manually connect to each one. If each device is configured as a server with a UUID, can i scan that UUID and establish a connection?

Comment: @conopizda2 this would work on Android, but not on iOS. iOS does not expose the devices UUID to the user or app. For security reasons every device gets a identifier completely unrelated to the UUID. There is no way to match a UUID with an identifier.

Comment: No.  There is no way to identify a device without connecting to it.  You could try and put some data in the device advertisement but there isn't much space and I am not sure it would work

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, that clears up a lot of things. If Bluetooth cannot be done like this and TCP sockets are not possible, is there any other wireless communication protocol that could be implemented using a QR code? Maybe it can be added as a functionality